# Tablesorter jquery display total rows in the html table above table

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using Tablesorter and a mod of Tablesorter

1. http://tablesorter.com/docs/
2. http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/tablesorter/tablesorter.htm

I have a pretty simple question. In the mod functionality, how can I display the total visible row count above the table? I understand it will require a textbox to display the result, but how do I get that value? It should display something like, "total rows retrieved: 100".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a header row:

```
<tr>
    <th colspan="6" class="total">
        Total Rows: <span>0</span>
    </th>
</tr>
```

and then enter the information without needing tablesorter at all ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/31/))

```
var totalrows = $('table tbody tr').length;
$('.total span').html(totalrows);​
```

Comment: Simple and straight thanks.... additionally I used another but will mark your answer as the inspiration to mine.

Answer (score 1):

Used fudgey's logic but wanted my total row outside the table, so modified like the below.

```
Total Rows: <span class="total"> 0  </span>
<table cellspacing="1" class="tablesorter"> 
....  </table>
```

javascript:Where Active is the class of my tr rows.

```
var totalrows = $('.Active').length;

$('.total').html(totalrows);
```